# Failed to store data though Ajax in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4, modal-dialog

I'm trying to store data using Ajax in Laravel from a bootstrap modal. Here are my codes:

`route.php`

```
Route::get('/repository/', 'RepositoryController@index');
Route::post('/repository/', 'RepositoryController@store');
```

and now 
`repository.index`

```
@section('popups')
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="row row-bg">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="text-field" style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 10px;" id="name" name="name" placeholder="URL name*: ">
                  {{$errors->first('name','<span class="error_message postShake"><i class="fa mr fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Please enter the name</span>')}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="text-field" style="width:100%;  margin-bottom: 10px;" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Enter the URL*: ">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <textarea class="text-field" style="width:100%;  margin-bottom: 10px;" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter the URL*: "></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="whiteButton" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="add" name="add" class="blueButton">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); 
           var name=$(this).find('input[name=name]').val();

           //post Ajax
           $.post('/repository', 
            {
                "name": $(this).find('input[name=name]').val(),
                "url": $(this).find('input[name=url]').val(), 
                "description": $(this).find('input[name=description]').val()
            }, function(data){
               // console.log(data);
           }, 'json');
        });
    });
</script>
@stop
```

And in the `RepositoryController.php`

```
<?php

class RepositoryController extends BaseController{

    public function index(){
        return View::make('repository.index');
    }


    public function store(){

        $validation=Validator::make(Input::all(), Link::$rules);

        if($validation->fails()){
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages());
        } 
        $link = new Link;

        $link->name=Input::get('name');
        $link->url=Input::get('url');
        $link->description=Input::get('description');

        $link->save();
        return Redirect::route('repository.index');
    }


}
```

`Link.php` model

```
<?php

class Link extends Eloquent{

    public static $rule= ['name'=>'reuiqred',
                          'url'=>'required',
                          'description'=>'required'];

}
```

In the console, it gives me an error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

What might be the problem? Also the validation error messages are also not appearing on the modal.

Comment: ajax and redirection together doesn't make any sense in the first hand.

Comment: How can I make this code work? I'm learning Ajax in Laravel

Comment: instead of redirect, you should use `Response::json()`

Answer (score 0):

change your json with the following

```
$('#add').click(function() {
name = document.getElementById('name').value;
url = document.getElementById('url').value;
description = document.getElementById('description').value;
$.post('/repository', {'name': name, 'url': url, 'description': description}, function(data) {

   var parsed = JSON.parse(data);

    var html = 'content echoed in your post function goes here';

    $('#requestStatus').append(html);
}).success(function() {
    $('#comment').val('');
    $('#sentSuccess').html('Something happened!').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
}).fail(function() {
    $('#sentFailed').html('Nothing happened').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
});
```

and your post function

```
public function store(){

$name = Input::get('name');
$url = Input::get('url');
$description = Input('description');

$data = array('name' => $name , 'url' => $url);
    $validation=Validator::make($data, Link::rules());

    if($validation->fails()){
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
    } 
    $link = new Link;

    $link->name= $name;
    $link->url= $url;
    $link->description= $description;
    $link->save();
//now to return a message 
    echo json_encode(array('name' => $name, 'url' => $url, 'description' => $description);
}
```

and your Link should be

```
<?php
class Link extends Eloquent{
public $table = 'table_name';

public static function rule()
{
$rule= ['name'=>'reuiqred',
                      'url'=>'required',
                      'description'=>'required'];
return $rule;
}
}
```

Comment: I still have the same problem: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: fixed the code of post function please have a look instead of redirect try sending data back(which I did)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your routes

Something like that:

```
Route::get('/repository/index', 'RepositoryController@index');
Route::post('/repository/store', 'RepositoryController@store');
```

Also fix your js.

```
 $.post('/repository', 
        {
            "name": $('#name').val(),
            "url": $('#url').val(), 
            "description": $('#descsription').val()
        }, function(data){
           // console.log(data);
       }, 'json');
```

Your id instead of name attrs

And fix your controller

```
return Renurn::json($link);
```